# Finding Twin Primes - Have logic finished, but it won't print anything when the program is ran

Tags: c, primes

A twin prime is a prime number that is exactly two larger than the largest prime number that is smaller than it. For example, 7 is a twin prime because it is exactly two larger than 5. But 17 is not a twin prime because the largest prime less than 17 is 13.

My logic for this program is as follows:

```
*ask number of twin primes that want to be found
 *loop until desired number of twin primes are found
   *loop numbers 2 - 1million (declared as variable j)
    *check if that number 'j' is prime - if so flag it
     *if 'j' is not flagged, subtract 2 from 'j' (call that new number 'TPcheck')
      *Check if 'TPcheck' is a prime, if so, print 'TPcheck' and the first number 'j'
```

When I run this program, I enter the number of twin primes to be found, but it just continues to run, and doesn't print anything on the screen. I think that the problem may have something to do with the order of the loops and if statements(or maybe the way that they are nested), but I have tried a ton of different ways and nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int i = 2, count = 0, TPcheck, j, k, flag;
int numberofTwinPrimes;
printf("Enter how many twin primes you want to find");
scanf("%d", &numberofTwinPrimes);


while(count < numberofTwinPrimes)
{
    for(j = 2; j <= 1000000; ++j)
    {   for(i = 2; i < j; ++i)
        {
            if(j%i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;                   
                continue;
            }

            if(flag == 0)
            {
                TPcheck = j - 2;
                for(k = 2; k < TPcheck; ++k)
                {
                    if(TPcheck%k == 0)
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if(flag == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%d\t %d\t", TPcheck, j);
                        count++;                
                    }
                }
            }           
        }

    }
}                       


return 0;

}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize flag and you never set it to zero (in order to print a value your code asks if flag == 0)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can be simplified quite a bit.

1. Define a function that simply returns whether a number is a prime number or not.
2. Use that in a loop using a very simple logic.

Here's a working version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int isPrime(int n)
{
   int stop = 0;
   int i = 0;

   // Special case for 3.
   if ( n == 3 )
   {
      return 1;
   }

   // If n is not divisible by numbers up to sqrt(n),
   // then, n is a prime number.
   stop = (int)(sqrt(n));

   // We can start at 3 and increment by 2
   // There is no point dividing by even numbers.
   for ( i = 3; i <= stop; i +=2 )
   {
      if ( n%i == 0 )
      {
         // It is not a prime number.
         return 0;
      }
   }

   // Checked divisibility by all numbers up to sqrt(n)
   // This is a prime number.
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   int numberofTwinPrimes;
   printf("Enter how many twin primes you want to find: ");
   scanf("%d", &numberofTwinPrimes);

   // Start checking at 3 and increment by 2.
   // There is no point checking even numbers.
   // When we find the required number of twin primes, stop.
   for(i = 3; i <= 1000000 && count < numberofTwinPrimes; i += 2 )
   { 
      if ( isPrime(i) && isPrime(i+2) )
      {
         ++count;
         printf("%d\t %d\n", i, i+2);
      }
   }                       

   return 0;
}
```

Here's the output when `numberOfTwinPrimes` is `10`.

```
3    5
5    7
11   13
17   19
29   31
41   43
59   61
71   73
101  103
107  109
```

Answer (score 0):

This isPrime() function is faster than Fumu's suggestion:

```
/* function isPrime returns True if argument is prime number. */
boolean isPrime(int aNumber)
{
    int i;
    int limit;

    /* Numbers < 2 */
    if(aNumber < 2) { return False; }

    /* Even numbers. */
    if (aNumber % 2 == 0) { return aNumber == 2; }

    /* Odd numbers. */

    /* Only need to check odd divisors as far as the square root. */
    limit = (int)(sqrt(aNumber));
    for (i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2)
    {
        if( aNumber % i == 0) { return False; } 
    }

    /* Only prime numbers make it this far. */
    return True;
}
```

Two is the only even prime, so all even numbers can be dealt with very quickly.  Odd numbers only need to be tested with odd divisors less than or equal to the square root of the number: 9 = 3 * 3

There are faster methods, but they require construction of a table of primes.  For your program, something like this appears to be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Your code for checking a number is prime or not is not correct.

You should check the number never be divided any numbers less than the number.

Code of a function for checking a numer is prime or not is as follows:

```
/* function isPrime returns True if argument is prime number. */
boolean isPrime(int aNumber)
{
    int i;

    if(aNumber < 2) { return False; } 
    else if (aNumber==2) {return True;}

    for i=2 to aNumber-1
    {
        if((aNumber%i) == 0){
          return False;
        } 
    }

    return True;
}
```

I hope this give you some useful idea.